# elasticsearch - Increment counter or create document if not exists

Tags: java, elasticsearch, counter

I'm incrementing a counter in elasticsearch with this query:

```
{
   "script" : "ctx._source.value += 1"
}
```

However, I get an error if the document does not exist. I'm using the Java API and this is my code:

```
UpdateResponse updateResponse = client.prepareUpdate("app", "counters", "message")
                                      .setScript("ctx._source.value += 1", ScriptService.ScriptType.INLINE)
                                      .setRetryOnConflict(5)
                                      .get();
```

I'm getting a DocumentMissingException: [app][1] [counters][message]: document missing

What I want is update the document if exists, or create a document with "value"=0 if doesn't.

Comment: What do you get when calling `curl -XGET localhost:9200/app/counters/message` ? Can you show the document you're trying to update?

Comment: That's the point: There is no document yet. I want it to be created the first time the update is called. The structure of the document I want to create is: {"value":0}. Then, each time the update is called, the "value" field has to be incremented by 1.

Comment: checkout the [upsert](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/java-update-api-upsert.html#java-update-api-upsert)  example should help

Answer (score 3):

If the document exists but the field `value` doesn't exist then the query is

```
"script" : {
    "inline": "ctx._source.value = ctx._source.value ? ctx._source.value += 1 : 1"
}
```

If the document doesn't exist at all, Then the following would create the document with the `value` field

```
"script" : {
    "inline": "ctx._source.value += 1"
},
"upsert" : {
    "value" : 1
}
```

The above can be easily transformed to whichever client you might be using.